# How to use pop for multidimensional array in pythonic way

Tags: python, list

I want to remove the list items found in list B from the list A. This is the function I wrote:

```
def remove(A,B): 

    to_remove=[];
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            if (B[j]==A[i]):
                to_remove.append(i);

    for j in range(len(to_remove)):
        A.pop(to_remove[j]);
```

Is this the normal way to do it ? Although, this works completely fine (if typos, I don't know), I think there might be more pythonic way to do it. Please suggest.

Comment: If `A=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2]` and `B=[1,1,2]` do you wish to remove every match of 1 and 2 in A or only two 1's and 1 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that your function doesn't work right.  Try this:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 2, 3]
remove(A, B)
```

You'll get an `IndexError`, because the correct indices to delete **change** each time you do a `.pop()`.

You'll doubtless get answers recommending using sets, and that's indeed much better if the array elements are hashable and comparable, but **in general** you may need something like this:

```
def remove(A, B):
    A[:] = [avalue for avalue in A if avalue not in B]
```

That works for any kinds of array elements (provided only they can be compared for equality), and preserves the original ordering.  But it takes worst-case time proportional to `len(A) * len(B)`.

Comment: Forgot to think about this. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades, you could repair that in the original like so: `for i in reversed(to_remove): del A[i]`.  "The trick" in things like this is to delete starting from the largest index.  Then the other elements to delete retain their original positions :-)

Answer (score 5):

Convert `B` to a `set` first and then create a new array from `A` using a list comprehension:

```
s = set(B)
A = [item for item in A if item not in s]
```

Item lookup in a set is an `O(1)` operation.

If you don't want to change the `id()` of `A`, then:

```
A[:] = [item for item in A if item not in s]
```

Comment: One could convert them both to `set` and then use `A.difference(B)`

Comment: @WayneWerner That won't preserve the order.

Comment: True - I suppose it then depends on if one needs order preserved.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehenstion to the rescue:

```
[item for item in A if item not in B]
```

This however creates a new list. You can return the list from the function.

Or, if you are ok with loosing any duplicates in list `A`, or there are no duplicates, you can use `set` difference:

```
return list(set(A) - set(B))
```

One caveat is, this won't preserve the order of elements in `A`. So, if you want elements in order, this is not what you want. Use the 1st approach instead.

Comment: This solution doesn't preserve original order of items in `A`, right? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @aga Oh yes. Forgot to mention that. 'll add.

Answer (score 2):

What about list comprehension?

```
def remove(removeList, fromList):
    return [x for x in fromList if x not in removeList]
```

Also, to make life easier and removing faster you can make a set from list `removeList`, leaving only unique elements:

```
def remove(removeList, fromList):
    removeSet = set(removeList)
    return [x for x in fromList if x not in removeSet]

>>> print remove([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And, of course, you can use built-in `filter` function, though someone will say that it's non-pythonic, and you should use list generators instead. Either way, here is an example:

```
def remove(removeList, fromList):
    removeSet = set(removeList)
    return filter(lambda x : x not in removeSet, fromList)
```

Comment: Here you're creating a new `set` in each step, so this is still `O(N**2)`.

Comment: @hcwhsa that's why I love SO: when you answer someone's question, somebody'll point you out to some mistakes in your own answer. I never thought that list comprehension will make new `set` on each step in this situation, thank you so much for your comment!